# expected value of $1/(e^x + 1)$ when x is a poisson random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Assume $x$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda$. Does anyone know how to compute the following?

$$E_x\left[\frac {1}{e^x + 1}\right]$$

Any resealable lower bound is also appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "resealable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function $g(x)=\frac1{e^x+1}$ is convex over $\{x\in\mathbb R\colon x\ge0\}$ (it can be seen that for $x\ge0$, $f''(x)>0$) and because $X$ only take non-negative values (it has a Poisson distribution), Jensen's Inequality implies
$$E(g(X))>g(E(X)).$$
So, we have that
$$E\left(\frac1{e^X+1}\right)>\frac1{e^{E(X)}+1}=\frac1{e^\lambda+1}.$$

Also, since $h(x)=\frac1x$ is convex,
$$E\left(\frac1{e^X+1}\right)>\frac1{ E\left({e^X+1}\right)}=\frac1{E\left(e^X\right)+1}.$$

And since
$$E(e^X)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^x \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda e}=e^{\lambda(e-1)},$$
another bound is given by
$$E\left(\frac1{e^X+1}\right)>\frac1{e^{\lambda(e-1)}+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac1{e^X+1}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{e^k+1} \mathbb{P}(X = k) = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!(e^k+1)}$$

For a lower bound notice that $e^k+1 \le 2e^k$ so

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac1{e^X+1}\right] \ge \frac12e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!e^k} = \frac12 e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda/e} = \frac12 e^{\lambda(e^{-1}-1)}$$